# how to input all values of a column in JSF page?

Tags: excel, jsf, primefaces

i want to know if there is a possibility in JSF or primefaces that allow to input all values of a column( from excel for example ) on a JSF page and submit it to the managed bean. thats mean getting the values in a list in the managed bean .

i designed this figure to let youunderstand what i mean :

[image]

Do you have an idea how we can do that ?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Where is the data coming from? Database? read from file? input from user? Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: the data is coming from an excel file .. i need to copy all values from Excel and to past them in an input on JSF page like the Shema that i realised

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a possibility. Here are the necessary steps involved.

1. Upload an Excel file by using, for example, [`<p:fileUpload>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSimple.jsf) component:

   ```
   <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <p:fileUpload value="#{bean.file}" mode="simple"/>
       <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" action="#{bean.upload}"/>     
   </h:form>
   ```

   and

   ```
   public class Bean {
       private UploadedFile file;//getter + setter
       private List<String> data;//placeholder
       public void upload() {
           if(file != null) {
               extractData(file.getInputstream);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Read the file contents in `extractData` method by using, for example, [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) library:

   ```
   private void extractData(InputStream is) {
       HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
       HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
       List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
       for(Row row : sheet) {
           Cell cell = r.getCell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
           if(c != null) {
               String content = cell.getStringCellValue();
               data.add(String);
           }
       }
       this.data = data;
   }
   ```
3. Redisplay data by standard JSF means: bind the retrieved list to some iterative component, ajax-update it, etc.

Comment: i dont need to input the excel file but i need to copy manually the values of the columns in an input of JSF page then import them to managed bean ( Like the Shema to have an input that can get many values in one time).